# How do I have a sprite fade in onto the scene Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like my sprite to fade onto the scene rather than just plainly appear. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an SKAction [fadeInWithDuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/fadeInWithDuration:)